# Identity partial function with Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I have a function `partial()`, that takes a callable and arguments that have to be passed to it, and prefills the first argument of the callable.

How should I annotate its parameters for the type check to work, no matter which callable I pass to it.

```js
function foo(a: string, b: number, c: string) {
  console.log('foo', a, b, c)
}

function bar(a: string) {
  console.log('bar', a)
}

function partial(callable, ...args) {
  callable('identity', ...args)
}
```

If it helps, this is what I am currently trying, but doesn't quite work:

```js
  partial<T>(callable: (...args: [string, ...T[]]) => void, ...args: T[]) {
    callable('partial a', ...args);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to represent the rest of the arguments as a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), so that the compiler keeps track of the number and order of the different argument types.  It looks like this:

```
function partial<T extends any[]>(
  callable: (...args: [string, ...T]) => void, ...args: T
) {
  callable('identity', ...args)
}
```

So the type parameter `T` is already an arraylike type.  When you call `partial()`:

```
partial(foo, 1, "okay")  // "foo",  "identity",  1,  "okay" 
// function partial<[number, string]>(callable: 
//   (args_0: string, args_1: number, args_2: string) => void, 
//  args_0: number, args_1: string): void

partial(bar); // "bar",  "identity" 
// function partial<[]>(callable: (args_0: string) => void): void
```

You can see that for `foo`, `T` gets inferred as `[number, string]`, while for `bar`, `T` gets inferred as `[]` (the empty tuple).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXIgzlAJxjAHMAaRAIxzBAFtKBTAiiHfI0gSkQG8AoRIggJccADaMAdOLgk0AchRwFFDBUqsu-AL79+oSLARUMBTO0LESPAUJFgxkmXMWUzqxBm16D4aPBIAA5msBjiADwAKoiMAB5QjGAAJrheYACeANoAugB8aILC4eIYlJI4aFLVZiS4OFkc1hTVUlE5PAC8eYgAbnAwyS01BHU4Ufy2RRAlZZKKg0mwUBmerbW4PvohBGHiaMoUAIwUAERwANYYGac8iAD094inyqcUz4tgyzfvJ0LnVxuiH4j2Q-mMwVCMHCESytAYzAoTVI+TQM3EpXKjBwIKeQkwo1wAH0AAyWTjkLyEolHGj0JgsKl1IkAJnJ1i6PX6gwouKEG1JdIRjIFtLwVm4OG5yW2UPCaHcBC4AG4Hk9Toq3v9Pt9TsDQYYAiYdntYaj0ZiKogCcyyeKKZy+gNklwpc6gA)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly :D I was so close, yet so far